# What is the difference between "delete" and "Reflect.deleteProperty()"

Tags: javascript

I want to know what is the difference between this two similar operations? Each of them removes properties. But why we have possibility to delete them in two ways?

Comment: There are often multiple ways of doing the same thing in a large number of programming languages....

Comment: The docs explicitly state: `Equivalent to calling delete target[name].`, so there's zero difference.

Comment: It's a matter of preference. You can go either way. The return values of Reflect.deleteProperty() are nicer though. There are a 1000 ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 3):

There is actually no difference in the functionality of the two, just in the syntax. Reflect APIs are most useful when combined with Proxies or analogues don't exist.

[Here](https://github.com/xojs/xo/issues/14) is a discussion between the two.

Have a look at the usage example in the documentation: [`Reflect.deleteProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty) and [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from MDN ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty)):

> The static `Reflect.deleteProperty()` method allows to delete properties. It is like the `delete` operator as a function.

It does not have any side effect as far as I know.

Comment: You should link to the MDN article you are quoting according to their [attribution guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/About#Copyrights_and_licenses).

Comment: @HereticMonkey will do next time.  Thanks for Edit Alicia